# React-Native: TextInput size is getting increased automatically irrespective of numberOfLines prop

Tags: react-native, textinput

I have a `TextInput` as shown below,

```
 <TextInput
     style={{borderWidth: 1, borderColor: "#dedede", width: '90%',  marginTop: 20, borderRadius: 1}}
     placeholder={'Tell us more about our service'}
     multiline = {true}
     numberOfLines = {10}
     value={this.state.customerFeedback}
     onChangeText={customerFeedback => this.setState({ customerFeedback })}
     underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
 />
```

since I gave `numberOfLines = {10}`, if I type more than 10 lines text must be scrolled inside the `TextInput` area. But in my case size of the `TextInput` is gradually getting increased as show in below image,

[image]

If we look at `TextInput` there are more than 10 lines.

Can anybody let me know how to restrict `TextInput` area according to `numberOfLines` props? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I saw your code and one thing you are missing one more property for the style is maxHeight.
I add this in your code now you can copy and paste this code in your project.

```
{/*maxHeight:200 */}
<TextInput
 style={{borderWidth: 1, borderColor: "#dedede", width: '90%',  marginTop: 20, borderRadius: 1,maxHeight:200}}
 placeholder={'Tell us more about our service'}
 multiline = {true}
 numberOfLines = {10}
 value={this.state.customerFeedback}
 onChangeText={customerFeedback => this.setState({ customerFeedback })}
 underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
/>
```

I hope this will help :)

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you are missing is maxHeight property for the style in textInput , ive added `maxHeight:50`:

```
<TextInput
     style={{borderWidth: 1, borderColor: "#dedede", width: '90%',  marginTop: 20, borderRadius: 1,maxHeight:50}}
     placeholder={'Tell us more about our service'}
     multiline = {true}
     numberOfLines = {10}
     value={this.state.customerFeedback}
     onChangeText={customerFeedback => this.setState({ customerFeedback })}
     underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
 />
```

try once , and do check the expo snack [expo-snack](https://snack.expo.io/By9ZK6WJI)

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts